# The index 0 is out of range

Tags: java, exception, indexing

I'm getting a 'The index 0 is out of range' exception in the following try-catch block but I can't for the life of me figure out where the exception gets thrown?

```
try{           

        cs = this.con.prepareCall("{call "+storedProcName+"("+procParams+")}");

        for(int j = 0; j < params.length; j++){
            if (paramTypes[j].equalsIgnoreCase("Int")) {
                int x = 0;
                try{
                    x = Integer.parseInt(params[j]);
                } catch(Exception e) {}
                cs.setInt(j, x);
            } else if (paramTypes[j].equalsIgnoreCase("Boolean")) {
                boolean x = false;
                try{
                    x = (params[j].equalsIgnoreCase("True")) || (params[j].equalsIgnoreCase("T")) || (params[j].equalsIgnoreCase("1")) || (params[j].equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) || (params[j].equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
                } catch(Exception e) {}
                cs.setBoolean(j, x);
            } else if (paramTypes[j].equalsIgnoreCase("String")) {
                cs.setString(j, params[j]);
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Problem constructing callableStatement: "+e);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    }
```

Thanks to anyone having a look at this and maybe point me in the right direction!

Comment: Do you know for a fact the exception is thrown from that code, or could it be thrown from one of the cs calls?  (Which aren't in local exception handers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) parameter indexes start at 1 - so you probably just want

```
setString(j + 1, params[j]);
```

etc

Answer (score 4):

The indices for parameters in a `PreparedStatement` start at 1, not at 0.

So the first parameter has index 1. If you try to use 0 as an index, it will complain that that's not a valid index.

Answer (score 1):

The index of the first parameter is 1, not 0

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
System.out.println("Problem constructing callableStatement: "+e.getMessage);
```

to find out the stacktrace and the "trouble" line of code.

Answer (score 0):

`} else if (paramTypes[j]`

Shouldn't that be `params[ j ]`?

Comment: Oh, never mind.  Probably not.  But it's bad practice to maintain two arrays and rely on the size of one when traversing both.